# SQL select value and then use in sub query to replace string

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, cdata

In my sql table I have a number of values as follows;

```
<![CDATA[9435547092]]>
<![CDATA[Company Name]]>
```

Most of the rows have a CDATA wrap, I wanted to remove this from all the files so I was thinking a subquery would be good something like;

`SELECT value FROM attributes WHERE value LIKE "%<![CDATA[%";`

Would give me each value and then I was thinking to do

`SELECT REPLACE(SELECT value FROM attributes WHERE value LIKE "%<![CDATA[%";, "<![CDATA[", '') FROM attributes`

But this isn’t valid, anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use replace in select  for obatin the right string

```
    SELECT replace(value , "<![CDATA[", '')
    FROM attributes 
    WHERE value LIKE "%<![CDATA[%";
```

if you need store in databae then you need  updated

```
UPDATE attributes
set value =   replace(value , "<![CDATA[", '')
WHERE value LIKE "%<![CDATA[%";
```

but seems you are looking for the left string after  LIKE "%

```
select  right(value, length(value) - locate(value,']]')+2)
from attributes
WHERE value LIKE "%<![CDATA[%";  


UPDATE attributes
set value =  right(value, length(value) - locate(value,']]')+2)
WHERE value LIKE "%<![CDATA[%";
```

Comment: I get an error with that; `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT replace(value , "<![CDATA[", '')
    FROM attributes
    WHERE value LIKE ' at line 1` I corrected the spelling of the replace function above too

Comment: thanks, so that know shows the values like this; 
`VALUE ]]>` however when I preview this in the database row it hasn't saved it as the new value. do I need to run an update command too?

Comment: .. i have added  also another suggestion for rigth  string  ...hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select replace(replace(value, '<![CDATA[', ''), ']]>', '')
```

Note that if your actual value has "wraps", then this might affect the value.  I think a more generic method would be:

```
select (case when value like '<![CDATA[%]]>'
             then substr(value, 9, length(value) - 3)
             else value
        end)
```

Comment: That didn't work, it says rows were affected but doesn't seem like it. and yes I do need a more generic query as wrapped in the cdata could be anything. So I've got a table called attributes which has a value column and a lot of the valus are wrapped in `<![CDATA[%VALUE IS HERE%]]>` Any ideas why the above didn't work?

Comment: this stmt does not provide any change on data - it gives you an output as you wish.
How big is your table? How many rows does it have (more or less)?

Comment: @001221 . . . If you want to change the data you should use `update`.  I would recommend doing so with the logic in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
SELECT select SUBSTRING(value,10,LEN(value)-12) 
FROM attributes
WHERE value like '<![CDATA[%'
```

If needed where clause could be removed and as suggested above could be used with CASE statement.